# ArcObject C++ Quick Start Guide Loop layer in FileGDB

Tags: arcobjects, c++

Could anyone guide on how to create console app (c++) that use ArcObjects?

I've searched Google a lot on this topic but can't find any tutorial on how to do this.

You may wonder why would I use C++ instead of .Net since there are more examples in .Net. Recently I've read about performance of ArcObject on .Net vs Managed c++ in this [article](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#26b7a578-7854-4ff9-b96c-948eded73626.htm)

And noticed that in my application. Using managed C++ as class library (dll) to loop layer and do somethings with it may improve the performance of my app.

So I started to search on this topic a lot, but unfortunately I can't figure out how to do this.

Could anyone familar with using ArcObject in C++ guide me on how to create one?
Maybe a simple project that open layer in filegdb and loop?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Unfortunately, GIS SE is not a tutorial site, and recommendations  are too *opinion-based* for the  "Focused question / Best answer" model used here. Thete ate probably ways to improve performance  within your app, unrelated to the language, but that's a very different question.

Comment: Very sorry for that, you can close it. Since what I actually want is quick start guide on writing ArcObject in C++ but not performance-related. I'll leave my question as it is. Maybe someone want to ask somethings like me will see it. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: A good place to start is http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-cpp/componenthelp/ but as for the samples they were installed with the SDK for C++. There isn't much interest that I have seen evidence of for ArcObject programming with C++, personally even though I'm OK with C++ I write all my ArcObjects code with C#. What are you trying to do that would require the slight difference in speed between C# and C++? Not that there would be much difference as *managed* C++ is compiled via CLR and would be nearly identical to C#.